# How can i list all holidays' date for each country using holidays module in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-holidays

I am trying to find holidays' date with holidays package in python for many countries but, instead of writing one by one like this:

```
import holidays
for date in holidays.UnitedKingdom(years=2011).items():
    print(str(date[0]))

for date in holidays.Argentina(years=2011).items():
    print(str(date[0]))
```

I am trying to do this with a function like this:

```
for i in dir(holidays):
    for j in range(2010,2016):
        holidays.i(years=2011).keys()
```

I know that with loop every country's name is a string but I want to implement it as a loop, if you have any advice or suggestion please share with me.
thank you.

Comment: Please add to the question a sample of what your expected output should look like

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly: `pip show holidays`
and then copy the location into the `locationVariable`

```
import holidays
import os
locationVariable = ""
countries = [name.split(".py")[0].replace("_"," ") for name in os.listdir(locationVariable+"holidays/countries/") if name.endswith(".py") and  not name.startswith("__")]

print("List of countries are : " + str(len(countries)))

for i in countries:
    for j in range(2010,2021):
        try:
            print(getattr(holidays,i.title().replace(" ",""))(years=j).keys())
        except:
            print("unable to iterate "+i.title().replace(" ",""))
            break
```

seems like the formatting of the name is inconsistent(for `Hongkong`), please and use.

Make sure to mark is answered if helpfull.

Comment: Thank you for answer, it really helped me.